# Getting 'undefined reference to' function although I have clearly included the files

Tags: c

I have 3 files:

main.c

```
#include "fle.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     FILE *fptr = checkFile(argv[1]);
}
```

fle.c

```
#include "fle.h"

FILE *checkFile(char *path)
{
 ...
}
```

fle.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef FLE_H_
#define FLE_H_

FILE *checkFile(char *path);

#endif
```

My makefile looks like this

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

As a minimal (non)working example, it throws an error

```
/main.c:4: undefined reference to `checkFile'
```

I'm curious why the checkFile function is surrounded by backtick from the left and apostrophe from the right, it doesn't seem right, but I don't think that's the problem.

I'd appreciate any help regarding this issue, it might be something trivial, but clearly I'm not skilled enough to resolve it myself.

EDIT: I have renamed the names from file to fle everywhere to prevent some collisions with the system libraries, but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Think of how you would compile this without the makefile. What command(s) would you use? Then look at the makefile and realise there is no reference to `fle.c` at all.

Comment: Including the right headers never helps with "undefined reference". You seem to have confused something. (One exception, if you define the function in a header .... shudder).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was hoping the building process would do this automatically, good to know I have to also include it in the makefile itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make is a macro language. It does not perform magic for you, although complex macros can certainly feel like black magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you include the declaration you need to link in the definition.  The easiest thing is to change the Makefile as follows:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c fle.c

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: "file.c", "fle.c", somebody has a typo. But I think it actually is not your answer. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch Fixed and I will revise if op changes question.

Comment: Now that I understand the principle, I can apply it to all my cases, I had more than one issue of the same kind.